# Why in List interface only add(int index, E element) returns void wheras all other add methods return boolean

Tags: java, list, collections, interface

Don't get me wrong - I understand why add methods deriving from Collection must return boolean, I just don't get why there is inconsistency with this one method - addAll both return boolean even though one of them doesn't have to.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The boolean return value is there to help you catch the case where you give it an empty list. The `add` method will always change your list so the return value would just always be true.

Comment: I still don't understand

Comment: This is actually not correct. It doesn't matter if the collection is empty or not. The crucial difference here is, that some collections allow duplicates and some don't. As lists always allow duplicates, `add(E element)` will always return `true` for every `List` implementation. As `add(int index, E element)` is only defined for `List`, it is not necessary to have it return something, as it will always add the element. Consider my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73358046/18143824) for more details.

Comment: Maybe I formulated my question poorly: I am aware that List implements Collection and thus add(E element) and addAll(Collection<E>  collection) both must return boolean because contract limits them so. My question was more related to add and addAll methods which are providing additional index arguments - those are not derived from Collection and one of those returns boolean (addAll) whereas the other returns void (add) - this is the inconsistency that I was talking about and when you look at those two methods @randypaq13 answer seems perfectly reasonable for me.

Answer (score 3):

Collection methods also cover sets. For sets, any time you add to it, it might have no effect, since sets cannot contain duplicates. So the boolean is there to indicate whether the method actually changed the collection.

In general, such Collection methods return booleans to indicate whether the collection was actually modifed by the method call.

This does not apply to the List method [`add(index, element)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add-int-E-). Anything that would prevent this adding an element to the list at the specified index would indicate an error, so it would cause an exception to be thrown.

Answer (score 1):

The [JavaDoc of Collection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#add-E-) says, that `add(E element)` returns `true`, if the collection has been changed. As there are collections that don't support duplicates, those won't be changed when adding an element that is already in the collection.

A List, on the other hand, supports duplicate elements. The [JavaDoc of List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add-int-E-) says, that `add(int index, E element)` **shifts any subsequent elements to the right (adds one to their indices)**. That means, the list will be changed *every time* you call `add(int index, E element)`.